# Folders within a Document Library in Powershell WSS 3.0 / SP2007

Tags: 2007, powershell, folder

I need to write a quick powershell script to do the following agains SP 2007

1. Show all the folders within a document library.
2. Count the documents within each folder.
3. Show the permissions on each folder within the document library.

Anyone got any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Any ideas to get this working ?

Comment: $site = new-object
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://wss/sites/Jamaame")
$web = $site.rootweb

$list = $web.Lists["Champa"]
$foldercount = $list.Folders.Count


foreach ($listItem in $list.Folders)
{

  write-host ($listItem.Name)



}

Comment: I have this , that I have written but it only shows the root folders , I need to find the amount of files within each root folder and the perms on them

Answer (score 0):

```
$StartingFolder = "\\sharepointportal\site\subsite"
$FolderList = gci $StartingFolder -recurse | ?{$_.psiscontainer}
foreach ($Folder in $FolderList){

          foreach($item in $folder)
          {
                $count++;
          }
"Folder: $($Folder.fullname) Count: $Count"
$count=0;
     }
}
```